# Uploading file to s3 bucket via nginx using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying upload file to s3 buckect through nginx,client side I'm using javascript .Can any one help me to achieve this.my nginx conf file
[nginx.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb4Vn.png)

-->here javascript this will send upload image(multipart image) to nginx with 'upload' url.[javascript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpIUD.png)

--> upload html file[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c26hQ.png)

note:In S3 buckect with upload name file got created ,when I open that file showing access denied(
`AccessDenied`
Access Denied)

Comment: Check S3 object permission

Comment: If thier is permission issue,how come I'm able to see file with the name 'upload' in my bucket.@PramodKharade

Answer (score 0):

Chnage conf folder or check missing any properties in .conf file

Answer (score 0):

Check your bucket read permissions. Your nginx.conf looks good. Usually this error comes when you don't have access to the s3 object you requested.